# Blazor server - how to disable specific UserIdentity authentication functionality?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

I use blazor server and have:

- enabled `Individual User Accounts` authentication
- created custom user entity extending `UserIdentity`
- created custom `dbcontext` extending  `IdentityDbContext`

I am confused about the default forms and functionality blazor provides - like password resets, mail verification,... - and would like to disable most of it. **I would be pretty happy to just have registration, login and logout.**

So, my questions are:

- Is mail the only possible option to register/login? I would like to use `UserName` field from `UserIdentity`
- Is it possible to enable/disable these user account functionalities; including forms?

Comment: Did you scaffold the Razor pages already?  You can rewrite the Login and Register pages to use a Name but you'll have to add  logic to keep them unique.

Comment: Yeah, but are the other pages disabled if they are not overridden? Are they still accessible via URL?

Comment: Yeah, you can remove all links to thos pages but if somebody types them in they will get there I think. Try it out.

Comment: Maybe scaffold those pages and then remove their content.